# CSS arrow. Only a portion of the arrow is being displayed

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to display a few words inside of a CSS styled arrow. I have figured out how to create an arrow with CSS which works fine. however, when I place the arrow within `<h2>`, complete arrow is not being displayed.

The source code is as follows

**HTML**

```
<div style="background-color: yellow;">
    <h2><span style="background: green;">This is what I want</span><span class="arrow-right"></span><span style="margin-left: 50px;">is this what you want?</span></h2>
</div>
```

**STYLE**

```
<style>
    .arrow-right::after{
        content: "";
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-top: 15px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;  
        border-left: 15px solid green;
    }
</style>
```

The output is as follows
[image]

The arrow pointer is not being displayed completely.  Am I using the elements wrongly?  I will need the div / h2 height to be bigger later, but at least that is not my concern right now since the arrow itself is not being displayed as desired.

**Edit:**
Sorry for my bad drawing.  This sample below is what I want but of course the arrow would be lots nicer I just used paints to give it a quick draw.

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly. Everything is in the right spot, you just need the full arrow to display?

Comment: plz add a fiddle of this.

Comment: I submitted an answer below. Let me know if the yellow must extend under the green. That's a simple adjustment. Or if there's something else that needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @Michael_B I added a sample picture.

Comment: I am really sorry everyone, I think I explained in a really bad way.  Hopefully the sample picture helps.  Really thanks a lot for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/61tc5em9/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="arrow">text text text</div>
    <div id="content">text text text text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height: 75px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

#arrow {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 75px;
}

#arrow::after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 37px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 38px solid transparent;  
    border-left: 50px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
}

#content {
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25px;
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any changes.

Comment: Really thanks for the css, I thought it would be easier than I expected.  Can I ask something really fast in here which isn't related to this topic though.  It's about clearfix

Comment: had two questions both  about `clear` but one of them is solved. Anyways to be short I have something like `<article></article>` which css `article{clear:both;}` which didn't work as well as putting a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` before the article element

Comment: alright, codes quite long but let me see if I can somehow shorten it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86525/discussion-between-wxr-and-michael-b).

Answer (score 1):

You need `font-size:0;` for the arrow.

```css
.arrow-right::after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid green;
    
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
}

span{
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: yellow;">
<h2><span style="background: green;">This is what I want</span><span class="arrow-right"></span><span style="margin-left: 50px;">is this what you want?</span></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations for improving your code and make it more dynamic:

- Use `:after` in the `statement` element itself (this way you will avoid
  the extra code in html and you can position the arrow relative to the element).
- Align it to the right using `left: 100%` (so it is always position to
  the right regardless of the width of the arrow).
- Use `top: 50%` and `margin-top: -(height/2)px` to center it vertically.

Just like this:

```css
.wrapper {
    padding: 2px 0;
    background: yellow;
}
.statement {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}
.statement:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;     /*change the border width to set the desired hieght of the arrow*/
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid green;          /*change the border width to set the desired width of the arrow*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%; 
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;   /*the element has height= 30px  (border-top + border-bottom) to center it -height /2 */
}
h2{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
     <h2>
         <span class="statement">This is what I want</span>
         <span style="margin-left: 50px;">is this what you want?</span>
    </h2>

</div>
```

Note that in this way you have a more semantic code  because you don't have dummy element in your html and if you want more statement it will put the arrow behind automatically like this:

```css
.wrapper {
    padding: 2px 0;
    background: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.statement {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}
.statement:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%; 
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;   /*the element has height= 30px  (border-top + border-bottom) to center it -height /2 */
}
h2{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
     <h2>
         <span class="statement">One statement</span>
         <span style="margin-left: 50px;">Good</span>
         <span class="statement">Two statement</span>
         <span style="margin-left: 50px;">Great</span>
    </h2>

</div>
<div class="wrapper">
     <h2>
         <span class="statement">Where is the arrow?</span>
         <span style="margin-left: 50px;">Do not worry about it</span>
    </h2>

</div>
```